# cropping images in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to detect a face and then crop it to use it in a face recognition algorithm. Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import Image

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('xD.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    print x
    print y
    print w
    print h
    img.crop((x,y,w,h))
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I print (x,y,w,h), it gives precise coordinates, but when I crop it, it gives me this error.

> img.crop((x,y,w,h))
>   AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'crop'

Comment: `roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]`  **is** the cropped image already.

Comment: alright then how can I save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('xD.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cropped = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite("thumbnail.png", cropped)
cv2.imshow("cropped", cropped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```